Given uncertain data, how can I calculate a "cheapest possible correction" with respect to an operator?
In the realm of inverse problems, what I am looking for is given an operator $$T : f \to T(f)$$ and a function pair, $$t\to f(t),c(t)$$ so that c measures "certainty" in some sense, so that $$c(t)\in[0,1]\\ f(t) \in \mathbb R$$
$c(t)$ should mean "certainty" of the function value $f(t)$ at $t$. In other words if c(1) = 0, then the value of f(1) should be very loose.
A trivial example of what I am looking for : If we set $$T\{g\}(w) = \int_{-\pi}^\pi g(t)e^{-w\pi i t}dt\\ f=\cases{\sin(t), |t|< 1\\0, |t| \geq 1}\\c= \cases{1, |t|<1\\0, |t|\geq 1}$$
Then I want the "solution" $\hat f$ to be ${\hat f}(t) = \sin(t)$ on the whole interval. Because it does not cost anything to change the function values where $c=0$, and it is the solution which presents the simplest or sparsest view through the eye of our operator T : the Fourier transform.
Own approach
Given the way that I have phrased the problem I suppose some kind of optimization framework would be reasonable.
$$\min_{\hat f} \left\{ |T{\hat f}| + |c(t)(\hat f (t) - f (t))|\right\}$$
I suppose linear least squares on a discretized grid or some convex optimization approach could deal with this.
